# How to override Indexer EAV class

Tags: configuration, overrides, xml

Based on the answer for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597448/multi-select-filter-in-layered-navigation#24810688, I need to override

```
Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Eav_Source
```

Here's the xml I've tried:

```
<models>
  <catalog_resource>
    <rewrite>
      <product_indexer_eav_source>CompanyName_MyModule_Model_Catalog_Resource_Product_Indexer_Eav_Source</product_indexer_eav_source>
    </rewrite>
  </catalog_resource>
</models>
```

But it has no effect. Any ideas?

Comment: have clear cache properly.Also need to check compiler enable or not

Comment: Ah. Right. I thought caching was disabled, but it was not. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per as,comment ,**it may be an issue with Cache** .After ***Clearing Cache the the rewrite will be working***